# Opencl - fail to run kernel on GPU

Tags: xcode, opencl, gpu, cpu

I am working on an XCode Opencl project (ACO for VRP problem). The kernel works well on `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU`, but when I use `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU`, Xcode fails to execute this project, with the errors:
[errors pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UhiNJ.png)

My platform is `Intel HD Graphics 5000 1536 MB`. I don't know why this happens. Is there anything I missed for extra GPU configuration?

Then I try a very simple Opencl example project, I found it works well on both CPU and GPU. My kernel (ACO for VRP problem) is a little complex with some global and private memory (no more than 10M).

I would be very appreciate if anyone can give me some advice.

---

I then tried a very simple kernel on `CL_DEVICE_TYPE_GPU`. Here is the kernel.

```
    __kernel void exchange(int M)
    {
        int i, k, t;
        double help[M], b;

        for (k = 0; k < M; k++) {
            help[k] = 0;
        }
        for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            b = help[0];
            t = 0;
            for (k = 0; k < M; k++) {
                if (help[k] < b) {
                    b = help[k];
                    t = k;
                }
            }
// --- help[i] = 1 OR help[k] = 1 OR just comment this line ---
            help[t] = 1;  //! error comes there
        }
    }
```

Again Xcode fails to compile it.  It seems that the error is from this line `help[t] = 1;`. If this line is replaced with `help[i] = 1;` or `help[k] = 1;` or just commented, this kernel will work. Can anyone explain why? Thanks!

Comment: There is not enough detail in this question to give a useful answer. I can only suggest divide and conquer as a general technique for debugging OpenCL code: Remove code from the end of the kernel and write out and inspect intermediate results, and keep doing that until it starts working, then add code back in to find out where it's going wrong. When you've found the code that's causing problems, try to isolate it in a new kernel, then debug that. (Or post that code here if you get stuck.) Finally, macOS OpenCL is very buggy in general, so you have that to deal with as well.

Comment: Are you sure your device/implementation even supports the `double` data type?

Comment: I also tried `float` data type with the same error.

Comment: You sure there is no kernel compile cache left over?

Comment: is it because variable length arrays are not supported?